# PySpark: Generate timestamp string from available data

Tags: python, pyspark

How can I transform a malformed timestamp string into one that is represented as days, hours, minutes, seconds?

Consider the following example:

```
# create df
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['1970-01-13T22:05:38.391+0000', '12.22:05:38.3910000']]), ["ts", "expectedValue"])

# initial date conversion
df = df.withColumn("ts_altered", F.date_format(F.col('ts'), 'd HH:mm:ss SSSSSS') )  # initial conversion

# try to remove a day
df = df.withColumn("ts_altered_minus1", F.date_sub(F.col('ts_altered').cast('timestamp'), -1))  # try to subtract a day
```

I am trying to generate the expected value

```
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|                  ts|      expectedValue|        ts_altered|ts_altered_minus1|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
|1970-01-13T22:05:...|12.22:05:38.3910000|13 22:05:38 391000|             null|
+--------------------+-------------------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Given my only input:

```
1970-01-13T22:05:38.391+0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code

below code I think should suffice your requirements

```
# create df
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['1970-01-13T22:05:38.391+0000',]]), ["ts"])

# try to remove a day
df = df.withColumn("ts_altered_minus1", F.col('ts').cast('timestamp')-F.expr("INTERVAL 1 DAYS"))

#convert to required date format
df = df.withColumn("ts_altered", F.date_format(F.col('ts_altered_minus1'), 'd HH:mm:ss SSSSSS') ) 

df.show()

#output
+----------------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
|ts                          |ts_altered_minus1      |ts_altered        |
+----------------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
|1970-01-13T22:05:38.391+0000|1970-01-12 22:05:38.391|12 22:05:38 391000|
+----------------------------+-----------------------+------------------+
```

The first problem in your code is date_format returns string column and not timestamp so casting it directly without specifying format while casting will return null and second problem was that date_sub returns a date and not a timestamp so you will use your hour min and seconds if you use date_sub